# Set random seed for PythonTeX document

Tags: python, latex, random-seed

I am a physics instructor and would like to use PythonTeX to write problems in LaTeX with random values.

I want to run pythontex3.py on the document and get a new set of random values. From what I can tell the python random module will choose a seed from the systems clock (that way you won't always get the same set of random numbers on launching python).

However pythontex3.py appears to always starts with the same seed, thus generating the same set pseudo random numbers every time.

Here is a MWE

```
    \documentclass{exam}
    \usepackage{pythontex}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{pycode}
    import random
    # Create large number with 3 significant digits
    Number=random.randint(100,1000)*1000
    \end{pycode}
    
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    The number \pyc{print(Number)} in scientific notation is
    \begin{choices}
        \CorrectChoice \pyc{print('%.2E' % Number)}
        \choice \pyc{print('%.2E' % (Number*1*10**random.randint(-10,-5)))}
        \choice \pyc{print('%.2E' % (Number*1*10**random.randint(-5,0)))}
        \choice \pyc{print('%.2E' % (Number*1*10**random.randint(5,10)))}
    \end{choices}
    \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

which generates the following on my machine.
[Screenshot of PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWZIT.png)

Answer (score 2):

why you are no providing random seed explicitly in your code?

```
random.seed() # use system time as a randomness source
```

or you can generate a reproducible sequence using

```
random.seed(2345)
```

Comment: Manually setting the seed is a good idea and what I'm going to use now.

I tried using 
        x=datetime.now()
        random.seed(x.microsecond)
to get a different seed every time I compiled but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the random seed with the your system's time and then tell pythontex to always run the python code. By default pythontex will only update if the python code has change since the last compilation.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
import random
# Set seed by clock's microsecond so that each 
# compilation will give new random values
from datetime import datetime
now=datetime.now()
# Manually set seed if reproducible sequence is desired
random.seed(now.microsecond)
# Create large number with 3 significant digits
Number=random.randint(100,1000)*1000
\end{pycode}
\begin{questions}
\question
The number \pyc{print(Number)} in scientific notation is
\begin{choices}
    \CorrectChoice \pyc{print('%.2E' % Number)}
    \choice \pyc{print('%.2E' % (Number*1*10**random.randint(-10,-5)))}
    \choice \pyc{print('%.2E' % (Number*1*10**random.randint(-5,0)))}
    \choice \pyc{print('%.2E' % (Number*1*10**random.randint(5,10)))}
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Then compile with

> pdflatex MWE.tex; pythontex3 --runall=true MWE.tex; pdflatex MWE.tex